# Hibernate 5.x to Hibernate 6.x alias issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am migrating from spring boot 2.7(hibernate 5.x) to spring boot 3.0(hibernate 6.x).
My database is Oracle 19c and I am using OracleDialect.

Problem is some of our entities in our legacy code have underscores as prefix for jpa entity fields.
What is happening is newer version of hibernate is prefixing the underscore to the generated queries which is a syntax error, it used to work fine in older version but not working in hibernate 6.x, and we cant rename the field names for now.

My entity look something like this:

```
@Entity("Tree")
@Table("TREE")
class Tree {
    @Id
    @Column("id")
    int id;

    @Column("PARENT_NODE_ID")
    int parentId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_NODE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Tree _parent;
}
```

In this case the generated query will look something like this:

```
select blah blah from TREE t inner join TREE  _1_a   on t.PARENT_NODE_ID = _1_a.ID
```

Here you can notice how '_1_a' was generated as alias for table TREE which is a syntax error since database doesn't support _ as prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this. I've opened the following issue:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16619

The workaround, of course, is to rename the field to something that complies with standard Java naming conventions.

Comment: Hi @Gavin King I'm seeing the same problem with Oracle and Hibernate 5.6.15.FInal

Comment: Sadly I cannot move to Hibernate 6.x and have many fields with the name '_id' and renaming is not an option.

I'd be happy to do a local patch, but SqlAliasStemHelper.java appears to be new in 6.x and I can't see what the 5.x equivalent is.  Any pointers gratefully received.